# iOS 13.0 UIMenu and UIAction for UIContextMenuConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I'm trying to use the new APIs introduced in iOS 13.0 Beta. I have downloaded Xcode 11.0 Beta 3 to be able to access these API.

Some of the code I found online does things like:

```
extension SingleViewController: UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate {
    func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { actions -> UIMenu<UIAction>? in
            // Creating Save button
            let save = UIAction(__title: "Save", image: UIImage(systemName: "tray.and.arrow.down.fill"), options: []) { action in
                // Just showing some alert
                self.showAlert(title: action.title)
            }

            // Creating Rotate button
            let rotate = UIAction(__title: "Rotate", image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.counterclockwise"), options: []) { action in
                self.showAlert(title: action.title)
            }
            // Creating Delete button
            let delete = UIAction(__title: "Delete", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash.fill"), options: .destructive) { action in
                self.showAlert(title: action.title)
            }
            // Creating Edit, which will open Submenu
            let edit = UIMenu<UIAction>.create(title: "Edit...", children: [rotate, delete])

            // Creating main context menu
            return UIMenu<UIAction>.create(title: "Menu", children: [save, edit])
        }
        return configuration
    }
}
```

This seems fine but doesn't even compile in my Xcode. The errors I get are:

`Cannot specialize non-generic type 'UIMenu' Replace '<UIAction>' with ''`

on creating configuration constant.

`Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

on creating save action.

and couple other similar errors.

I should also mention, I don't even have the constructors that are in this format:

```
UIAction(__title: "String", image: UIImage, options: Array)
UIMenu.create(...)
```

Why are these missing in Xcode-11 beta 3.0 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it changed. It's a beta! And I would expect it to change again, but for now, in beta 3, the initializer for UIAction is

```
init(__title title: String, image: UIImage?, identifier: UIAction.Identifier?, 
    handler: @escaping UIActionHandler)
```

UIMenu is not generic, and its initializer is

```
init(__title title: String, image: UIImage?, identifier: UIMenu.Identifier?, 
    options: UIMenu.Options = [], children: [UIMenuElement])
```

So here's a rewrite of your code that does compile under beta 3:

```
func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { actions -> UIMenu? in
        let save = UIAction(__title: "Save", image: UIImage(systemName: "tray.and.arrow.down.fill"), identifier: nil) { action in
            // whatever
        }
        let rotate = UIAction(__title: "Rotate", image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.counterclockwise"), identifier: nil) { action in
            // whatever
        }
        let delete = UIAction(__title: "Delete", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash.fill"), identifier: nil) { action in
            // whatever
        }
        let edit = UIMenu(__title: "Edit", image: nil, identifier: nil, children:[rotate,delete])
        return UIMenu(__title: "Menu", image: nil, identifier: nil, children:[save, edit])
    }
    return configuration
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help @matt, when I used your code, I get a compile error: Expression type 'UIAction' is ambiguous without more context. When I try to give UIAction a generic type: UIAction<UIMenu>( ... ) for example: Cannot specialize non-generic type 'UIAction'.

Comment: Am I missing an import or something?

Comment: Ok, I got UIAction to compile with this: let action = UIAction(__title: "Test", image: nil) { _ in
            
        }

Comment: And UIMenu with: let menu = UIMenu<UIAction>.create(title: "Menu", children: [action])

Comment: Did you accidentally revert to beta 2? I thought this was about beta 3... Just copy and paste the code I provided, directly into a view controller or view controller extension, in beta 3. It compiles.

Comment: You're right, I was trying at my home machine which has Xcode 11 beta.. Not 3. Thanks so much matt.

Comment: This is now fixed in Beta 5, the __title initializers are not necessary anymore.

Comment: @RalfEbert Excellent! As I said in the first sentence of my answer, I expected that.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 11.0 Beta 5, you can now write:

```swift
extension SingleViewController: UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate {
    func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { actions -> UIMenu? in
            // Creating Save button
            let save = UIAction(title: "Save", image: UIImage(systemName: "tray.and.arrow.down.fill")) { action in
                // Just showing some alert
                self.showAlert(title: action.title)
            }

            // Creating Rotate button
            let rotate = UIAction(title: "Rotate", image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.counterclockwise")) { action in
                self.showAlert(title: action.title)
            }
            // Creating Delete button
            let delete = UIAction(title: "Delete", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash.fill"), attributes: .destructive) { action in
                self.showAlert(title: action.title)
            }
            // Creating Edit, which will open Submenu
            let edit = UIMenu(title: "Edit...", children: [rotate, delete])

            // Creating main context menu
            return UIMenu(title: "Menu", children: [save, edit])
        }
        return configuration
    }
}
```

- The classes are no longer generic e.g. `UIMenu` instead of `UIMenu<UIAction>`.
- Comprehensive Swift initializers let you drop optional params, which have reasonable default values e.g. `image`, `attributes` and `identifier`.
- No more `UIMenu<UIAction>.create(...)` or `UIAction(__title:...)`. They're all real initializers now, yay!

Comment: Awesome! I'll take another look with Beta 5. Thanks Glen!

Answer (score 0):

On swift 5, this works:

```
extension ViewController: UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate {
func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { actions -> UIMenu? in
        // Creating Save button
        let save = UIAction(title: "Save", image: UIImage(systemName: "tray.and.arrow.down.fill")) { action in
            // Just showing some alert
            self.showAlert(title: action.title)
        }

        // Creating Rotate button
        let rotate = UIAction(title: "Rotate", image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.counterclockwise")) { action in
            self.showAlert(title: action.title)
        }
        // Creating Delete button
        let delete = UIAction(title: "Delete", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash.fill")) { action in
            self.showAlert(title: action.title)
        }
        // Creating Edit, which will open Submenu
        let edit = UIMenu(title: "Edit...", children: [rotate, delete])

        // Creating main context menu
        return UIMenu(title: "Menu", children: [save, edit])
    }
    return configuration
  }
}
```